# Linkedin API - get full data

Tags: php, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I try to make an script to get data from LINKEDIN, i am able to get many of information about profile like name, mail, phone, picture url and so on, unfortunately how ever I try I can't get to informations like work experience and many other.

My Request looks like:

```
   $xml_response = $linkedin->getProfile("~:(id,first-name,last-name,interests,publications,patents,languages,skills,date-of-birth,email-address,phone-numbers,im-accounts,main-address,twitter-accounts,headline,picture-url,public-profile-url)");
```

This work correctly, but lets try to add companies

Error:

> I added it at the end of  `$linkedin->getProfile` and here is the
>   error message what I get:
>
> [message] => Unknown field {companies} in resource {Person}

Full function looks like:

```
public function linkedinGetUserInfo( $requestToken='', $oauthVerifier='', $accessToken=''){
    include_once 'linkedinoAuth.php';

    $linkedin = new LinkedIn($this->config['linkedin_access'], $this->config['linkedin_secret']);
    $linkedin->request_token    =   unserialize($requestToken); //as data is passed here serialized form
    $linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   $oauthVerifier;
    $linkedin->access_token     =   unserialize($accessToken);

    try{
        $xml_response = $linkedin->getProfile("~:(id,first-name,last-name,interests,publications,patents,languages,skills,date-of-birth,email-address,phone-numbers,im-accounts,main-address,twitter-accounts,headline,picture-url,public-profile-url,educations,companies)");
    }
    catch (Exception $o){
        print_r($o);
    }
    return $xml_response;
}
```

Documentation I found (but didn't help me ) 

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields

I expect I miss something really stupid but cant figurate it out, can somone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinkedIn provided all these fields before May 12th 2015.

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,industry,associations,interests,num-recommenders,date-of-birth,honors-awards,three-current-positions,three-past-positions,volunteer,location," +

"positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker))," +

"educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes)," +

"publications:(id,title,publisher:(name),authors:(id,name),date,url,summary),"+

"languages:(id,language:(name),proficiency:(level,name)),"+

"skills:(id,skill:(name)))";

"courses:(id,name,number),"+

"recommendations-received:(id,recommendation-type,recommendation-text,recommender))";

"patents:(id,title,summary,number,status:(id,name),office:(name),inventors:(id,name),date,url))";

But, they have updated their APIs link:https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

According to which only these
Profile API — /v1/people/~ 
Share API — /v1/people/~/shares 
Companies API — /v1/companies/{id}

endpoints will be active, Rest require a Apply with Linkedin /Partner with Linked association.

phone-numbers,im-accounts,main-address,twitter-accounts,headline would come under r_contactinfo which needs a Apply with linkedin

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `companies`, you must use `positions` keyword.

```
$xml_response = $linkedin->getProfile("~:(id,first-name,last-name,positions)");
```

Positions field description in the following address.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/positions